# Replicating DynamoDB stream events using RDBMS

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, rdbms

Using MySql or Postgres (or some other RDBMS) is there a way to replicate DynamoDB's stream functionality? That is, when any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE query is executed on a table, an event is created which can be consumed by another process which listens for the events created by the table.

A DynamoDB stream makes this very easy but I would like to try and avoid DynamoDB if possible.

I was thinking some sort or stored procedure but I'm not sure if this will work.

Is this possible?